# "configuration could not be verified - is the username or password wrong?"

Tags: email, passwords, thunderbird

I have enabled the two-step verification to my gmail account. I have tried for application specific password for Thunderbird, but still Thunderbird showing this error message. And the same case with outlook.com email account. How can i configure my email accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem before, you have to double check the configuration. 
Have a look at here: http://davmail.sourceforge.net/thunderbirdimapmailsetup.html